# C++ - I want to combine data from pointer of vectors of strings into a static vector of strings in the following format

Tags: c++, vector

My vector of strings with dynamic size based of what user wants

```cpp
std::vector<std::string>* allTags = new std::vector<std::string>[tvSize];
```

Filling the allTags variable

```cpp
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tvSize; i++)
    allTags[i] = ParseData(vals[i]);
```

Now suppose that size of allTags pointer is 3 and following are the values in each:-

```cpp
allTags[0] = { "0", "1", "2"}

allTags[1] = { "a", "b", "c"}

allTags[2] = { "X", "Y", "Z"}
```

I want to combine the data of all 3 allTags in vector of string say combined_data. But I want to do it in the following way:-

```cpp
combined_data[0] = "0->a->X"; combined_data[1] = "0->a->Y"; combined_data[2] = "0->a->Z";

combined_data[3] = "0->b->X"; combined_data[4] = "0->b->Y"; combined_data[5] = "0->b->Z";

combined_data[6] = "0->c->X"; combined_data[7] = "0->c->Y"; combined_data[8] = "0->c->Z";

combined_data[9] = "1->a->X"; combined_data[10] = "1->a->Y"; combined_data[11] = "1->a->Z";
```

And so on. But I'm not able to come up with an algorithm for this. Can anyone help?

Comment: *My vector of strings with dynamic size based of what user wants* -- ???.  Are you aware of the purpose of `std::vector`?  It seems you've missed the whole point of what `std::vector` is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: Simplest solution is to have n nested loops where n is equal to tvSize. If n is not constant try recursion.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>* allTags = new std::vector<std::string>[tvSize];` --  Why do you want to do this?  Isn't this: `std::vector<std::string> allTags(tvSize);` what you really want to accomplish?

Comment: @LazarĐorđević I tried using recursion but I couldn't do it properly. Can you help me with a piece of code that works for my case?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Dynamic size because I don't know how many columns a user want.

Comment: @SAHILSINGHDHESI -- What does the word "dynamic" mean?  Doesn't it mean "variable size"?  Isn't a vector a container that has dynamic size?  So why are you using `new[]` when the whole purpose of a `vector` is to eliminate the need to use `new[]`?  A `vector` has `push_back`, `emplace_back`, `resize`, and `insert` member functions, that can change the number of entries in a vector.  There is no need for `new[]` here.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I want to keep data in different vectors man. What's so hard about it to understand? A user who wants to enter name, surname, and number will enter 3 for size. Then the user can continue to enter name (which will go to allTags[0]), surname (which will go to allTags[1]), and number (which will go to allTags[2]). For adding values to allTags[0], allTags[1], and allTags[2] I will just simply use pushback().

Comment: @SAHILSINGHDHESI *What's so hard about it to understand?* -- `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` -- This is what you are really trying to do?  Again, a `std::vector` removes any need for `new[]`.  This is the whole point of `vector`, but it seems you've missed the entire reason for vector usage.  You can have a vector of vectors, a vector of vectors of vectors, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ignoring the alleged fact that I missed the point of what vectors are all about, do you have a solution to my problem because what we two are debating on has nothing to do with my problem to begin with.

Comment: The comment section is for comments, not answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```cpp
vector<string> function(int lvl)
{
    if (lvl == tvSize) return vector<string>(0);
    
    vector<string> r; // some compilers will complain because of ()
    vector<string> v = funtion(lvl + 1);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < allTags[lvl].size(); i++)
    {
        if (v.size() != 0)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < v.size(); k++)
            { 
                string result = allTags[lvl][i];

                //result += new string("->").append(v[k]); - memory leak
                string pom("->");
                result += pom.append(v[k]);
                r.push_back(result);
            }
        }
        else{ r.push_back(allTags[lvl][i]); }
    }
    
    return r;
}
```

Read [std::vector documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).
What you want is all permutations on every level, so complexity is O(n^(r + 1)), where n is number of elements in every row and r is tvSize in your example, and you can't do much about that, but if you don't need every permutation you could exclude some element on any level of recursion. So if you don't need permutations with 'c' your algorithm will be faster for O(n^(r + 1 - l)), where l is level of 'c'.

Comment: `if (lvl == tvSize) return vector<string>(0);` --> `if (lvl == tvSize) return {};` -- Does the same thing, believe it or not.

Comment: I can't believe, but everything is possible.

Comment: The brace-initialization is what does the magic.  It didn't exist before C++11.

Comment: Also, I would suggest a solution that doesn't use `new`.  Right now, your solution has a memory leak.  Just remove the `new` in the line that concatenates onto the result.

Comment: Well teachers just mentioned old ways, I was to lazy to try something else. Thank you for mentioning. It is so easy today to forget new when using C# often.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the suggestion. I've taken care of the dynamically allocated vectors at the end of the function using `delete[]`.

Comment: @LazarĐorđević I get output like the following using that code (which is close to what I want). `"0->TIER_1", "0->TIER_1->TIER_2", "0->TIER_1->TIER_2->TIER_3", "0->TIER_1->TIER_2->TIER_3->TIER_4", "0->TIER_1->TIER_2->TIER_3->TIER_4->TIER_5"`. But I'm expecting something like following. `"0->TIER_1", "0->TIER_2", "0->TIER_3", "0->TIER_4", "0->TIER_5"`.  I'll see if I'm able to tweak your code to make it work. Thanks a lot for showing me the way man.

Comment: @SAHIL SINGH DHESI Now code is edited, very stupid mistake.

Comment: @LazarĐorđević The result is still the same and I'm not able to figure out how to proceed. It still keeps appending instead of creating new record.

Comment: @SAHILSINGHDHESI sorry again, I had code in my editor, but made mistake while editing post. Use debugger, to understand what happens in recursion.

Comment: @LazarĐorđević As far as I can see the code is still the same and yielding the same result. Can you recheck please>

Comment: @SAHILSINGHDHESI you just need to move result in inner loop, to store only last  iteration.

Comment: @LazarĐorđević tried. Couldn't figure out. I'm totally new to recursion. Never used it before.

Comment: @SAHILSINGHDHESI well last edit works like you want? Also I think you are not new to debugger, so you are free to use it.

Comment: @LazarĐorđević Yes, the last edit you made worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. I have marked your answer as accepted one.